# Xaml layouts properties

Tags: xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am making windows 8 app in c#. Are there any attributes in Xaml that makes a items in toolbox

```
layout_width="match_parent"
layout_height="wrap_content"
```

like in android xml?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xaml, if you make a [grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.rowdefinitions) with rows like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefintion Width="*"/>
        <RowDefintion Width="Auto"/> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Rows that have `Auto` `Width` resize to fit their contents.  Rows that have `*` `Width` equally share the available space with other `*` `Width` Columns.  To create an item that fills its container, simply put the control in a `*` row and column and set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` on the control to `Stretch`.

To get a control that wraps to the next line, simply use a [`WrapGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid.aspx).

Comment: How about if I have a list of Buttons and I have a listview as parent? * or Auto doesn't seem to have any effect on the Buttons, it just appears as default.